# Is it possible to provide a web service in a Android device without network card?

Tags: android, web-services, nic

I have a android-based device without any network card. But I want to provide a service which just works like a web server for my hybrid app, so the app could access this service by WebView.

`The service I want to construct in my android app must access the SQLite database and render the data to some html templates`, I only want to access this service by my own app locally, so it is OK whether the device has a network card or not.

In all, I want to find a solution of local web service in android.

Comment: what you exactly want??

Comment: If you have all the data which you want to display in the WebView locally (including JS and CSS files) then it's not a problem

Comment: @PsyGik I want to handle the data more flexible, since the size of data in database is not small. Thus, if I render all data to html to generate static files, the storage would be the problem.

Comment: If your HTML content has some external dependencies like jquery or any external css then it needs Internet to load it.

Comment: @jankigadhiya I want to find a solution to provide a service for a hybrid app which can use this service as a web service, while I can not and don't need to install a real web server, since the device has no network card and doesn't need to provide this web service for other app locally or remotely.